# Specify Import Row Range for SQL Server Task Wizard

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, csv

I would like to import a csv file into an empty table in SQL Server Developer 2016, using Task Wizard.  I know with BULK INSERT there are options to specify firstrow and lastrow; does Import Wizard have a similar feature?

Comment: Pretty sure there is an option to skip x rows....probably the first x, not from say 100-200..

Comment: Right.  I was wondering if I was missing s range option.  Oh well.

Comment: Did you get what you needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as I suspected, task wizard does not have the ability to select import range.  I ended up using bulk import and using the FIRST_ROW and LAST_ROW options.

Answer (score 0):

The wizard only has the option to skip the first x rows...more complex than that would need to be a regular SSIS package, or some pre-processing of the file before the wizard picks it up.

Alternatively, import the whole file to a staging table and then trash the rows you don't need, or push the ones you do want into the correct destination table in a T-SQL statement.